# Can I serve gzipped JSON on GitHub Pages?

Tags: jquery, http-headers, compression, gzip, github-pages

I have a JSON file on GitHub pages, it's about 2 MB uncompressed. I access that file via jQuery's `$.get()` method. I'd like to gzip the file, which shrinks it to about 500 KB, but when I put the gzipped file on GitHub pages, `$.get()` doesn't work with an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token`

I think the problem is that GitHub pages doesn't set the `Content-Encoding: gzip` header on the JSON file, and the GET request thinks it's dealing with a plain JSON file. Is there any way to either:

1. Force GitHub pages to add the `Content-Encoding: gzip` header to a `.json` file, OR
2. Configure the AJAX request so that it knows it's dealing with a gzipped JSON file, even though the server hasn't told it that the content is zipped

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Github pages is already gziping html, css, js, json,... It's useless to try to do better by gziping json yourself.

A 1.3M json is sent as 357KB one by github pages. [See here](http://statiktest.github.io/test/) and click on "load json" link.

Comment: It's not - in my case I have large objects, e.g. a 100mb WASM blob. It does not fit in the 100mb github pages limit. Compressed to gz it falls down to 32mb.